# I hate 5 x 5 x 5 pentagon in python

Tags: python, loops

[I need 6 pentagon 5 small ones(inner) and 1 large one(outer), those 6 pentagon's 5 sides should be in 5 different colors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gb6fV.jpg) I am new to python programming , couple of days before I learned **nested for loop** in python.

The thing is when I run my code the looping takes so much time to stop and I hate that and I want my program to draw only 5 little pentagon with 5 different color and my code goes like this :

```
import turtle;
count = 5;
turtle.speed(5);
for steps in range(count) :
  for color in ['blue','red','green','pink','yellow'] :
    turtle.color(color);
    turtle.forward(100);
    turtle.right(360/count);
    for moreSteps in range(color) :
      for color in ['blue','red','green','pink','yellow'] :
        turtle.color(color);
        turtle.forward(50);
        turtle.right(360/count);
turtle.done()
```

please  somebody help me to get this Thank You.

Comment: Does it work right now?

Comment: That code wouldn't run. Make sure you pasted your indentation *exactly* correctly for us to see.

Comment: One issue is `range(color)`.  The `range` function expects an integer argument, but `color` is a string, so this will give an error.  There are also some indentation errors in the posted code.

Comment: Just as a BTW, the `[]` around your color lists aren't necessary. Nor are the semicolons that you ended most of your lines with. And your spacing is incorrect - the code actually won't run as you have it here right now on the website.

Comment: You have too many for loops. Do you want to draw one of each color? Then you don't need the `for steps in range(count)` (you will enumerate 5 colors) or the inner most `for color in ['blue','red','green','pink','yellow'] : (you already did that once in the outer loop).

Comment: @MattiVirkkunen  Sorry for making the indentation wrong I have changed the code now please do a read  -thank you

Comment: Have you considered writing a function to draw a pentagram? Using a function would help you, because when you have a bug, it's either in the calling code or in the function code, this it makes searching for it easier.

Comment: @TomKarzes No passing string in range will also work in python . sorry for making my indentation wrong i have edited please have a look and help me.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt No I have read how to make function in python I am just a beginner in python.

Comment: @tdelaney No i want to have my 5 sides of polygon with 5 different colors

Comment: Then your question is unclear: There, you say you want to draw pentagon with different colors, now you want each pentagon with different colors on each side. Which is the case? Both perhaps?

Comment: @Akash  No.  Try it.  Type `range('red')` to the interpreter.  It will give an error.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt I have uploaded the expected output please check that.

Answer (score 0):

All the comments are helpful. Put the color in the most outside loop, so that it stays the same for each pentagon. Then avoid drawing on top of the previous pentagon, by moving after each pentagon for a bit. Something like:

```
import turtle 
count = 5 
turtle.speed(5) 

def drawfivepentagons(size=100):
    for color in ['blue','red','green','pink','yellow'] :
        turtle.color('white')
        turtle.left(60)
        turtle.forward(size*2)
        turtle.color(color) 
        for steps in range(count) :
            turtle.forward(size) 
            turtle.right(360/count) 


drawfivepentagons(100)
turtle.forward (20)
drawfivepentagons(50)

turtle.done()
```